# How do a Criteria polymorphic join in JPA?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have a project that have a modeling like this:

```
public abstract class Actor{}
public class Person extends Actor {}
public class Organization extends Actor {}

public abstract class Role{ @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="ID_ACTOR") }
public class Customer extends Role{}
public class Employee extends Role{}
```

I would like to get a `List<Role>` which plays a particular Actor:

```
public List<Role> getRoles(Actor actor) {
  CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Role> criteria = builder.createQuery(Role.class);

  //How to do this filter using Criteria API (JPA 2.1)?

  return query.getResultList();
}
```

The SQL below makes the job:

```sql
SELECT 'Customer' as role, c.id as id, c.id_actor as actor
FROM customer c
left join person p on p.id = c.id_actor
left join organization o on o.id = c.id_actor
where c.id_actor = ?

UNION 

SELECT 'Employee' as role, e.id as id, e.id_actor as actor
FROM employee e
left join person p on p.id = e.id_actor
left join organization o on o.id = e.id_actor
where e.id_actor = ?
```

Comment: Have you gone through this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212905/polymorphic-jpa-query-with-criteriaquery-api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem making a bidirectional relationship between Actor and Role class:

```
public abstract class Actor{ @OneToMany(mappedBy="actor") List<Role> roles }
public class Person extends Actor {}
public class Organization extends Actor {}

public abstract class Role{ @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="ID_ACTOR") Actor actor }
public class Customer extends Role{}
public class Employee extends Role{}
```

That way I could get the `List<role>` which plays a particular Actor:

```
public List<Role> getRoles(Actor actor) {
    return actor.getRoles();
}
```

Initially I would like to avoid the bidirectional relationship, but I realized that in this particular case, there are direct benefits